# How to display profile fields with no data in BuddyPress profile view?

Tags: buddypress

It seems like BuddyPress hides profile fields without data in profile view. 
How can I change this functionality? So that all fields gets displayed, even if they haven't been filled up?

Comment: Hi, askign support related questions for third part plugins are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your best bet is to contact the plugin developer directly on their support form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [template overload](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#how-is-this-useful) of this file: `buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\profile-loop.php`

Then find this code:

```
<?php if ( bp_field_has_data() ) : ?>

    <tr<?php bp_field_css_class(); ?>>

       <td class="label"><?php bp_the_profile_field_name(); ?></td>

       <td class="data"><?php bp_the_profile_field_value(); ?></td>

    </tr>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And change it to:

```
<tr<?php bp_field_css_class(); ?>>

   <td class="label"><?php bp_the_profile_field_name(); ?></td>

   <td class="data"><?php bp_the_profile_field_value(); ?></td>

</tr>
```

**EDIT**: We need to force the fetching of empty fields...

So also find this:

```
<?php if ( bp_has_profile() ) : ?>
```

And change to this:

```
<?php $args = array( 'hide_empty_fields' => false, 'hide_empty_groups' => false ); ?>

<?php if ( bp_has_profile( $args ) ) : ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have already tried this but it doesn't work! It keeps hiding the empty fields.

Comment: Are you sure that you are editing the correct template?  Add some text to your template and see if it appears.

Comment: yes I am sure! I did add var_dump and the text appears!

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer.